# Why do I get random errors by using celluloid?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, celluloid

I need to make API calls to a webservice in order to retrieve date.
For this purpose I created a sample in order to get familiar with celluloid.
Here I ll user the openweather API for "training" purpose.
The ultimate goal is to run multiple requests in concurrently.

my booking class (booking.rb) fetches data

```
    require 'celluloid'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

    class Booking
      include Celluloid


      def initialize

      end

      def parse(url)
        p "back again"
        begin
          buffer = open(url).read
          p JSON.parse(buffer)['cod']
        rescue => e
          "fuck"
        end

      end

    end
```

and this is how I run it:

```
require 'celluloid'
Celluloid.shutdown_timeout = 10

begin

  pool = Booking.pool

  %W(
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlin,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
).each_with_index do |weather, i|
    p i
    #Booking.new.async.parse(weather)
    pool.future.parse(weather)
  end
rescue => e
  p "ex #{e}"
end

p "start"
```

Now I do get different error messages when I run it several times:

```
ruby run_booking.rb
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
"start"
D, [2015-06-11T21:20:06.351274 #33316] DEBUG -- : Terminating 9 actors...
E, [2015-06-11T21:20:16.356649 #33316] ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!
➜  booking  ruby run_booking.rb
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
"start"
D, [2015-06-11T21:22:19.172770 #33344] DEBUG -- : Terminating 9 actors...
W, [2015-06-11T21:22:19.173145 #33344]  WARN -- : Terminating task: type=:finalizer, meta={:method_name=>:__shutdown__}, status=:receiving
    Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.
```

So I am wondering what's going on here? Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm happy to see you're experimenting with Celluloid. I am glad my answer(s) seemed to have helped this time. Come visit our Google Group if you need more help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/celluloid-ruby ... I'm part of Celluloid and I'm excited to see you're gaining experience.

Comment: @digitalextremist The support you are providing is awesome, also in the other replies i ve seen from you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 0. Your program is finishing before `Celluloid` does its work.

You need to use the method shown in #2 to avoid that. You need to `join` each `Future` to make sure all the information is retrieved and parsed... Otherwise you just fired off a ton of asynchronous calls that do not `block` ... which means nothing stops the program from exiting.

When in doubt, just add `sleep` to the end of your program, until you can figure out how you want to gracefully finish. So far the code you showed is incomplete.

---

### 1. Use the new version `Celluloid` like this:

- https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/0.17.0-Prerelease

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'celluloid', github: 'celluloid/celluloid', branch: '0.17.0-prerelease', submodules: true
```

Then when you `require` the `Celluloid` library, use this:

```
require 'celluloid/current'
```

---

### 2. Just use Futures. You don't need a pool at all, it will slow you down:

```
results = []
booking = Booking.new

%W(
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlin,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Munich,de
).each_with_index do |weather, i|
  p i
  results << booking.future.parse(weather)
end

#de Turn the futures into actual results by calling `.value` on each future:
results = results.map(&:value)
```

---

### 3. Use `http.rb` with `Celluloid` support:

- https://github.com/httprb/http.rb#celluloidio-support

Add `Celluloid::IO` to your `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'celluloid-io', github: 'celluloid/celluloid-io', branch: '0.17.0-dependent', submodules: true
```

Then use `HTTP` instead, and pass in `Celluloid::IO` socket types. Here's the example from `http.rb` itself:

```
require "celluloid/io"
require "http"

class HttpFetcher
  include Celluloid::IO

  def fetch(url)
    HTTP.get(url, socket_class: Celluloid::IO::TCPSocket)
  end
end
```

That call right there uses evented TCP, which goes great with your actor which has concurrent outbound gathering calls.