# ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds. How to solve this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actor, rails-migrations

I am trying to create a Rails model or migration. Whenerver I run the commands :

```
rake db:migrate
```

Or when I run the command rails g model myModel name:string

I get when the migration is being created the error:

```
E, [2016-08-30T20:49:03.838740 #28489] ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!
```

Comment: That error is coming from Spring. What is the exact version of Rails you're using? Also, post your gemfile, as well as the versions. That error can also be caused by certain gems.

Comment: This could be an error on celluloid, see this question for approaches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789795/why-do-i-get-random-errors-by-using-celluloid